# CREATE TABLE USING Oracle DATA_SOURCE

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a table using ORACLE as a data source using spark query but getting an error.

%sql
CREATE TABLE TEST
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
url "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost.com:1560:SCOTT",
driver "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
dbtable "SCOTT.EMP",
user "usr1",
password "paswd1"
)

Error in SQL statement: ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:46)

Answer (score 0):

This happends due to following reason :

1. Jar files for oracle driver is not available or Not compatible. Please check the jar and see if the class is available
2. Java Version you are using is not compatible.

Please share more details on Spark Version, Jar version and java version you are using for a resolution